# Checkmarx high vulnerability issue SQL injection

Tags: java, sql-injection, checkmarx

I am getting a checkmarx HIGH vulnerability issue SQL Injection.

requirement is user can insert any SQL query in the text area, on click on submit this query passes through request payload and server side it is being hold using request body annotation to pass across the layer.

vulnerability 1 :- saying this request is not sanitized.

vulnerability 2 :- second place is where I am doing executeUpdate for the sql query using Statement object as I can not use PreparedStatement, there is no dynamic parameter available. whatever query it was in text area is being executed directly.

I have tried HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(sqlQuery) and StringEscapeUtils but it fails to resolve the vulnerability.

The requirement is like this only I had to give text area to the user to put the query so that server can take it and execute it directly.

Any suggestion ? how to resolve it !!
Thanks

Comment: *whatever query it was in text area is being executed directly* - well that is very dangerous isn't it

Comment: Is your question "how do I make this secure", or "how do I make this alert go away?" If you have to run SQL directly from the user (really consider if you do), security needs to happen in a lot of layers. Managed access to this functionality, a SQL user (or user(s) as appropriate) with extremely limited rights, etc.

Comment: @ScaryWombat agreed but this is a feature for couple of user one or two and controlled by role.

Comment: @CollinD how to I make this vulnerability go away !! Yeah it is validating the user at server layer and its rights to execute the query before really interacting with the database

Comment: @KundanSaini You're baking a vulnerability into your application in my opinion.

Comment: @CollinD any suggestion to make it more secure and same time passes with checkmarx scan.

Comment: You make the vulnerability go away by changing your app to not directly execute SQL entered by users. Your entire design is flawed from a security standpoint, and you can't just pretend it's not. Your question is like *I drive around with a paper bag over my head. The person giving me my driving test says that's dangerous and won't give me a passing grade.. How do I keep driving around with a paper bag over my head and still pass my test?*. The answer: "You can't. Quit being silly and pull the bag off your head."

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks Ken !! Let me change the design, it doesn't make sense to have this feature with the security threat.

Answer (score 1):

CW answer:

There is no way to allow users to enter arbitrary SQL safely.

Checkmarx is correct in warning about this as a security vulnerability.

Change the design of the application so that it does not accept arbitrary user input and execute it as code (e.g. SQL queries). This is the definition of an injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one solution to solve an SQL-Injection : Parametrize yours queries !

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

Checkmarx captures lot of False Positive scenarios - and it's justifiable as to warn user. But the problem is, even if you write validation functions to sanitize the inputs, it still flags them as bug - biggest issue of this tool.

Furthermore, it captures SQL Injection bugs even with MongoDB.

My recommendation is, **just add validation functions which removes unnecessary characters, checks string length, data type, etc. That's good enough.** Don't bother if Checkmarx still captures that as error. As rightly said - Checkmarx is far far behind from perfection.